# Delete all changes (not commit) compared to the remote branch

Tags: git

I am new to Git so this question may seem obvious. I checked out a branch from Github to work locally. After making some changes, I realize I don't want those changes anymore (I have not committed). Is there any way I can delete all the changes so that the local branch is the same as the remote branch.

I am aware that I can make a commit and then `git reset --hard HEAD~1`. Just wondering whether there is any solution without the need to commit first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend you first, stash your changes, see that you are okay with the loss of your code, and then drop the changes:

```sh
# 1.
git stash

# 2.
# check that everything is fine

# 3.
git drop
```

---

But if you are confident, that your changes should really go, there is a faster way.

Depending if your changes are either staged or not, the quickest way is to just do the following

```sh
git checkout .
```

This **will discard** all of your local changes.

If your changes are staged, you can un-stage them with

```
git restore --staged .
```

and then execute the first command to discard changes.

Comment: I would emphasize the git stash, perhaps move it as the first suggestion ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply stash your changes

```
git stash
```

And, then, drop (discard) the stash

```
git stash drop
```